# Handling java string into native C/C++ for Android Studio+NDK

Tags: java, android, c++, c, android-ndk

I am trying to build a program using Android Studio1.3.2 + NDK + Windows7.
I want to pass a string from Java function to Native C function (const char*).

**The native C function declaration is:-**

```
public native int HRFromJNI(String path);
```

**The Java function call is:-**

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(HRFromJNI(path)));
```

**The Native C function is:-**

```
extern "C" {
  JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
  Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_HRFromJNI
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,jstring path)
  {
    int HRval = 0;
    char *Path;

    Path = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars( env, path, null) ;

    HRval = filefunction(Path);
    return HRval;
  }
```

**The function called by the Native C function is :-**

```
int filefunction(char* filename)
{
FILE* file = fopen((char*)filename,"w+");
//Reads value from the file and returns it.
.
.
.
}
```

But i get error "**Base operand of -> has non-pointer type JNIEnv{aka _JNIEnv}**"

Is this the correct way of passing string to Native C code, or is there any other way to assign a string from Java to const char* ?

Comment: You're using the C syntax (`(*env)->`), and the error is if it was C++ (where you need to write `env->`.

Comment: BTW, I think you've forgotten to call `ReleaseUTFChars`.

Comment: What is the use of calling ReleaseUTFChars ??

Comment: Freeing the memory that `GetStringUTFChars` allocates to hold the string data. It's a memory leak if you don't call `ReleaseUTFChars`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change below line:

```
Path = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars( env, path, null) ;
```

To:

```
Path = env->GetStringUTFChars( env, path, JNI_TRUE) ;
```

Pass jni boolean variable, instead of passing null.

Comment: `extern "C"`, though. I don't get it.